# Do an action while any checkbox state is modified with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, onclick, action

In my programm, I fill my interface with a lot of checkbox by this way :

```
void VGCCC::addMaterialToUI(QDomNodeList _materialNodeList, QWidget* _areaWidget, QLayout* _layout, QWidget* _layoutWidget, int _maTable)
{
    for(int i=0; i< _materialNodeList.count();i++)
    {
        QDomElement materialElement = _materialNodeList.at(i).toElement();
        QString elementFile = materialElement.attribute("file");
        QString elementId = materialElement.attribute("id");
        QString elementLabel = elementId;
        elementLabel += "  -  ";
        elementLabel += materialElement.attribute("label");
        QCheckBox* checkbox = new QCheckBox(elementLabel);
        _layout->addWidget(checkbox);
        _layoutWidget->adjustSize();
        _areaWidget->setMinimumHeight(_layoutWidget->height());
        _areaWidget->setMinimumWidth(_layoutWidget->width());

        configuration c;
        c.path = (m_igmPath+elementFile).toStdString();
        c.id = elementId.toInt();
        c.name = elementLabel.toStdString();
        if(_maTable==0)
        {
            m_materialSectionMap[checkbox] = c;
        }
        else
        {
            m_materialPostMap[checkbox] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to retrieve these "abstract" checkbox. More exactly, if one of these checkbox is checked, I would like to call another function like this :

```
    connect(anyCheckbox,SIGNAL(stateChanged(anyCheckbox)), this, SLOT(doSomethingFunctionIfCheckboxIsChecked()));
```

The difficulty is that in my UI, these checkbox didn't exist, so I can't connect them to my function. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Is there same action or for one checkbox - one diffeirent action?

Comment: This is the same action for every checkbox.

Comment: so, what's the problem to create connection in loop?

Comment: I've tried to do so, but my application is crashing, and I am not sure this is the best way to solve my problem (I'll update my post)

Comment: Where exactly you create a connection? It must be **after** creation an object.

Comment: Your connect call in the question is wrong. In Qt, signals and slots require matching argument types. You can see the correct way to connect stateChanged signal to a slot in my answer.

Comment: @talamaki, no his connection has a right to life in its structure but it will fails because a signal must take only type, not a final target. Any signal can be write like this: `void someSignal(int)` and call like this (for example): `connect(sender, SIGNAL(someSignal(int)), this, SLOT(someSlot()));` and it will work. So when you `emit someSignal(1)` it will call connection you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can e.g. collect pointers to your checkbox objects to a list so can access or "retrieve" them later.

You can connect each checkbox's `stateChanged` signal to a same slot which is then called when state of any of the checkboxes is changed. In the slot you can cast the `sender()` to a checkbox if you need to know which specific checkbox is in question. Another alternative is to use [QSignalMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html).

In your class declaration:

```
private slots:
    void checkboxStateChanged(int state)        

private:
    QList<QCheckBox*> m_checkboxes;
```

In your class definition:

```
void VGCCC::addMaterialToUI(QDomNodeList _materialNodeList, QWidget* _areaWidget, QLayout* _layout, QWidget* _layoutWidget, int _maTable)
{
    ...
    QCheckBox* checkbox = new QCheckBox(elementLabel);
    m_checkboxes.append(checkbox);
    connect(checkbox, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)), this, SLOT(checkboxStateChanged(int)));
    ...
}

void VGCCC::checkboxStateChanged(int state)
{
    // Here your can e.g. call doSomethingFunctionIfCheckboxIsChecked()

    QCheckBox* checkbox = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());
    if (checkbox)
    {
        // checkbox points to the object whose state changed
    }

}
```